# sorting product price using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a sorting price function using jquery, i am able to sort the price but the result that is fetched is not displayed in proper manner, the result that i get will be duplicated

```
<select class="form-control" name="price-sorting">
   <option value="l2h">Low - High Price</option>
   <option value="h2l">High - Low Price</option>
</select> 


      <!-- Products Grid-->
<div class="isotope-grid cols-3 mb-2">

<?php foreach($data['shops'] as $shop) : ?> 


      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="product-card"  data-price="<?php echo $shop->product_price; ?>">
          <a class="product-thumb" href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/shops/show/<?php echo $shop->product_id; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo URLROOT;?>/img/product/<?php echo $shop->product_img1; ?>" alt="<?php echo $shop->product_title; ?>"></a>
            <h3 class="product-title"><a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/shops/show/<?php echo $shop->product_id; ?>"><?php echo $shop->product_title; ?></a></h3>
              <h4 class="product-price">OMR <?php echo $shop->product_price; ?></h4>
              <div class="product-buttons">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm btn-wishlist" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Whishlist"><i class="icon-heart"></i></button>
                <a href="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/shops/show/<?php echo $shop->product_id; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toast data-toast-type="success" data-toast-position="topRight" data-toast-icon="icon-circle-check" data-toast-title="Product" data-toast-message="successfuly added to cart!">Add to Cart</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on("change", ".form-control", function() {

 var sortingMethod = $(this).val();

 if(sortingMethod == 'l2h')
 {
  sortProductsPriceAscending();
 }
 else if(sortingMethod == 'h2l')
 {
  sortProductsPriceDescending();
  }

  });
 function sortProductsPriceAscending()
  {
  var products = $('.grid-item');
  products.sort(function(a, b){ return 
 $(a).data("price")-$(b).data("price")});
 $(".isotope-grid").html(products);

 }

   function sortProductsPriceDescending()
   {
   var products = $('.grid-item');
     products.sort(function(a, b){ return $(b).data("price") - 
      $(a).data("price")});
   $(".isotope-grid").html(products);

  }


  </script>
```

This is the main page displayed in a grid format
[image: before sorting]

This is the result i get after i sort any price, it will show the result but will duplicate twice

[image: after sorting]

Comment: `l2h`, `h2l`, .... what, you too good for `asc` and `desc`? :P  lol, threw me off my game there for a bit

Comment: @Taplar not even close to being good ..i can change it ..lol :)

Comment: Ok, first of, what kind of value does the data-price contain?  It is only numeric, or does it have a $ in there?

Comment: @Taplar its numeric, no characters

Comment: Ok, secondly, your loop creates multiple `.grid-item`, and you are trying to append all the sorted products to the grid-items, which is incorrect.  You are going to want to sort the grid-items, and then append all the grid-items to whatever their shared parent is.

Comment: @Taplar i tried to do it but its not working i still dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Update with what you attempted?  Also, what is the direct parent of all the grid-items?

Comment: @Taplar i a have a div which hold a class of `<div class="isotope-grid cols-3 mb-2">` and its the parent that hold all the grid items, i have edited my question

Comment: Sweet, it looks like you're really close.  One sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the change to sort the grid items, you have to change your sort logic to find the nested product card so you can get the prices for the comparison.

```
function sortProductsPriceAscending() {
  // change variable name, so it's clear what it contains
  var gridItems = $('.grid-item');

  gridItems.sort(function(a, b){
    // we are sorting the gridItems, but we are sorting them on the nested
    // product card prices.  So we have to find the nested product card
    // to get the price off of
    return $('.product-card', a).data("price") - $('.product-card', b).data("price");
  });

  // when you put the grid items back on the container, just append them rather
  // than using html().  Append will just move them.
  $(".isotope-grid").append(gridItems);
}
```

```js
$(document).on("change", ".form-control", function() {
  var sortingMethod = $(this).val();
  
  if(sortingMethod == 'l2h') {
    sortProductsPriceAscending();
  } else if (sortingMethod == 'h2l') {
    sortProductsPriceDescending();
  }
});

function sortProductsPriceAscending() {
  var gridItems = $('.grid-item');

  gridItems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $('.product-card', a).data("price") - $('.product-card', b).data("price");
  });

  $(".isotope-grid").append(gridItems);
}

function sortProductsPriceDescending() {
  var gridItems = $('.grid-item');

  gridItems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $('.product-card', b).data("price") - $('.product-card', a).data("price");
  });

  $(".isotope-grid").append(gridItems);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="price-sorting">
  <option value="l2h">Low - High Price</option>
  <option value="h2l">High - Low Price</option>
</select>

<div class="isotope-grid cols-3 mb-2">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="product-card" data-price="1.00">$1.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="product-card" data-price="10.00">$10.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="product-card" data-price="5.00">$5.00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried your function but its still not sorting , its just refreshing

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing?

Comment: i mean when i choose a sorting option, the gird-item div just refreshes and it doesn't sort

Comment: @J.Doe added a runnable snippet with some dummy grid-items

Comment: I think their is a problem with the way I  created the div content that's why it's not working..I will have to change it ..thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If Taplar answer is not working, only change the selector, ex:

```
gridItems.sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).data("price") - $(b).data("price");
});
```

I hope it is useful for you